# WSO2 ESB Connection Time Out while Load Testing

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am load testing `WSO2 ESB (4.6)` and get this error when the load hits about 20000 messages:

`TID: [0] [ESB] [2013-08-14 11:13:04,835]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  Connection time out after request is read: ip:port->ip:port {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}`

It's a pretty basic test, I am sending messages from SoapUI to the echo service using 10 threads over 200 seconds.

It runs till it hits about 20,000 messages and then the connection errors come up.

I have changed the performance settings in the ESB to the optimum levels as described here http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/01/esb-performance-65.

I have also found this problem reported on WSO2's site which describes the issue as occurring when the system is under high stress. But it gives no resolution.

I did try NIO transport instead of PTT but got the same result.

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2015?filter=11177&jql=project%20%3D%20ESBJAVA%20AND%20resolution%20in%20(Unresolved%2C%20Fixed%2C%20%22Won't%20Fix%22%2C%20Duplicate%2C%20Incomplete%2C%20%22Cannot%20Reproduce%22%2C%20%22Not%20a%20bug%22%2C%20Invalid)%20AND%20status%20in%20(Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened%2C%20Resolved%2C%20Closed%2C%20Postponed)%20AND%20text%20~%20%22Connection%20time%20out%20after%20request%20is%20read%22%20AND%20resolved%20%3E%3D%202013-01-30%20AND%20resolved%20%3C%3D%202013-07-04%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you make your client side connection as "keep-alive and redo the test?

Answer (score 0):

Please try increasing the max thread pool size on config files. Please do value change one at time.

```
<ESB_HOME>/respository/conf/synapse.properties
synapse.threads.max = xx
<ESB_HOME>/respository/conf/nhttp.properties
snd_t_max=xx
lst_t_max=xx
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried changing these values but they made no difference. Since then I have discovered that the issue stops when I turn off the BAM component. So now I am looking at what BAM is doing and how it is effect the performance of the ESB. I am running the default server static BAM mediator to connect to WSO2 BAM 2.20. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, all performance depends on how many components run in single machine and also memory and CPU speed and how much concurrent messages you going to process. However below link will help you to understand the mediator statistics http://wso2.com/library/articles/2010/06/wso2-esb-mediation-statistics-can-numbers-tell-about-your-soa

Answer (score 0):

Problem sorted - the client has decided not to use BAM.